# Reading unsigned char from .txt file using fread give different values

Tags: c, file-io, type-conversion, fread, unsigned-char

I have the following code snipped to read 16 unsigned char values from a .txt file.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{

 int i, j, k, load_size;
 unsigned char *buf;
 load_size = 16;
 buf = (unsigned char *)malloc(load_size);
 FILE *fin;
 fin = fopen("demo_input1.txt", "r");
 fread(buf, 1, load_size, fin);
 for(i=0;i<16;i++){
    printf("%d ", *buf);                         
    buf++;
 }
 system("PAUSE");


}
```

The file 'demo_input1.txt' contains the values **1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16**. But I am getting output in the console values **49 32 50 32 51 32 52 32 53 32 54 32 55 32 56 32**. Can anybody help me by telling me what is going wrong here? Thanks

Comment: You need fscanf and not fread.

Comment: 49 = 0x31 which is the ASCII code point value for `'1'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fread` is for reading raw inputs. As your file is formatted text, use the following:

```
int nums[SIZE];
int count = 0;
while( fscanf(fin, "%d", nums + count) == 1 ) {
  if(++count == SIZE) break; /* More than expected numbers in file */
}
```

Later you can print using:

```
for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    printf("%d ", nums[i]);                         
}
```

`fscanf` is one way to read formatted input from files. You can use `malloc`, `walking pointers` as shown in your original code snippet or as per your requirements.

Comment: 'fscanf(buf, "%d", nums + count)' should not it be 'fscanf(fin, "%d", nums + count)' ?? because, fin is the stream here.

Comment: @amin__ Sorry, it was a typo. Updated.

Comment: its ok. so, in case of formatted text there is no feasible file io to read all the data at once instead using looping?

Answer (score 0):

The other way of how this can be done is using `fgets()` to read the whole line to the buffer break the line using space as delimiter and later convert string to integers and store them or print them.

```
char buf[300];
int a[30],i=0;
while(fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),fin))
{
   char *p = strtok(buf," ");
   i = 0;
   while( p != NULL)
   {
      a[i] = atoi(p);
      printf("%d ",a[i]);
      i++;
      p = strtok(NULL," ");
   }
}
```

PS: When `fgets()` is used you need to have predefined large array to hold your input else it may lead to erroneous results.

Comment: This code can generate false values. E.g. this is your content: `10 11 12 13 14 15 16` and we assume the buffer is smaller and gets filled with: `10 11 12 13 1`, then you will cut the `14` in half, resulting in `1` and `4` values.

Comment: @Nidhoegger You need to keep your buffer large enough to hold the whole input. Else there is no use of `fgets()`

Comment: you could peek ahead after using `fgets` and check if file end or whitespace is the next char. If not, ignore last value and move file cursor back a bit.

Answer (score 0):

What is going on is completly correct, yet not what you expected. So, whats going on? You read 1 byte from the file, into a `char`, then you output it using `%d`, which will output as decimal. Have a look at an ascii table, if you read the `char` `1`, its ASCII value is `49`, `32` is space, `50` is `2`, and so on. You cannot just read plain numbers like that, your code, replacing the `%d` with `%c` would only work on binary files, but not on human readable files.

What you want to use instead of `fread` is `fscanf`, which works like `scanf` but reads from a file. There you can specify to read an integer, thus getting the whole numbers without the spaces. These you can check if they are smaller than `256`, if yes, cast to char.

Comment: so, there is no way to do that with fread? I need to use fscanf with looping?

Comment: @amin__ If you want to read the whole line then you can go for my approach .. fread() can be used to read the the predefined number of bytes and later do operations on that buffer as shown in my answer

Comment: Of course you can do this with fread if you want to, but it gets very complicated later on. As already stated, fread reads raw data. This is usable if you store your file in binary mode. You could of course use fread to read into an array until you reach the end of file or a space, then convert the array data to `unsigned char`, but thats very impractible.

Answer (score 0):

It is considering the ascii value of space as 32(ASCII for space).

Just make one simple change in the for loop.
Instead of %d use %c

```
for(i=0;i<16;i++)
{
  printf("%c ", *buf);                         
  buf++;
}
```